# Android Nested LinearLayout, Gravity not having expected results

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

Having a problem with nested LinearLayouts to use as a custom row in a ListView.

App is a kind of internal corporate phone book and this row will be repeated in the ListView.

The "Details Witheld" on the right looks fine when gravity is set to left for it, but if gravity is set to center then it appears half off the page.

I'd guess my parent LinearLayout is too wide for the screen but it's set as fill_parent so I don't see how.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Full XML source is below.

Aligned Left looks like this and I'd like Details to be a space in so it's centered above the Witheld.

[image: Aligned left looks like this.]

Aligned Center looks like this

[image]

Full XML Source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <!--  Left side name & post / parish -->
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="80"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtrowname"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Smtih, Mr John"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkblue_text"                
        android:textStyle="normal" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtrowpost"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12 Some Street, SomeTown.  SS11 1SS"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <!--  Details withheld on right -->
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtrowwitheld"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:text="Details Witheld"
      android:layout_weight="20"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:lines="2"
      android:maxLines="2"
      android:textColor="#FF0000"
      android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
      android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Image with layout_gravity as suggested by Ramesh
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making do without it being centered.

Answer (score 0):

try layout_gravity in place of gravity that will work and dont use line="2". it will automatically fit into 2 lines if width exceeds.

Comment: Thanks, See my edit above with how it now looks.  There is no longer the issue with it going off the page but it's not centered.